# backtick quote causing error in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `text`,
       `oc_product_to_category.product_id`
FROM `oc_product_attribute` AS pa
LEFT JOIN `oc_attribute_description` AS od ON pa.`attribute_id`=od.`attribute_id`
LEFT JOIN `oc_product_to_category` AS opc ON pa.`product_id`=od.`product_id`
```

the problem caused by `oc_product_to_category.product_id`. I removed that and it work. As I know I can do like this opc.`product_id` but why `oc_product_to_category.product_id` doesn't work?

Comment: What you got error just mention here

Comment: see "When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: Why are you joining table with alias `opc` using columns from other tables?

Comment: Why are you using backticks on identifiers that are not reserved words and have no spaces?

Comment: Have you got your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backticks aren't causing your problem in this case.

You aliased the table, but then used the original name in the column list. You need to refer to it by its alias.

```
 oc_product_to_category.product_id
```

should be

```
 opc.product_id
```

I recommend you remove all of the backticks and just write standard SQL. I see nothing in the query that justifies cluttering it with non-standard escape sequences; that includes TEXT as MySQL allows you to use it unescaped, along with a short list of other reserved words like ACTION, BIT, DATE, ENUM, NO, TIME and TIMESTAMP.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

In general, I avoid escaping identifiers, and I specifically avoid backticks because they are non-standard and non-portable. MySQL can handle the standard SQL quoting syntax of double quotes, if properly configured. On new databases I enable ANSI_QUOTES.

```
SET global sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
```

Though you should never do this on a production database, because it will change the behavior of existing queries. Once enabled, you'll be able to use ANSI (standard) quoting, but the side effect is you can no longer use double quotes for string literal values, however, that is also a non-standard practice which only works on MySQL and should be avoided.

Comment: @Kaii Actually, no. MySQL doesnt requre you to escape TEXT as a column name. You can check the docs. It is explicitly allowed. Besides that, MySQL will still try to parse the statement the correct way in the presence of other reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SELECT `text`,
       `oc_product_to_category.product_id`
```

To

```
SELECT `text`,
       `oc_product_to_category`.`product_id`
```

OR Simply remove back ticks on field/table name if it is not reserve word. Here `text` is reserve word of mysql so it is written in backticks like

```
SELECT `text`,
       oc_product_to_category.product_id
```

You can put back ticks on field name, table name. You are just putting here as combine of tablename and field name above that's why you getting error.

Comment: Or even better: remove those dreaded (and not needed) backticks alltogether

Answer (score 0):

`oc_product_to_category.product_id`

If you want to use backticks, then use it for your table and column separately, like this:

`oc_product_to_category`.`product_id`

Also, you have aliased your table, so use your alias, like this:

`opc`.`product_id`

But you do not need backticks in this case.